# Question on convergence of an ODE solution

Tags: limits, analysis, rate-of-convergence

If $|\dot{x}(t)|$ converges to zero and $t|\dot{x}(t)|^4$ converges to zero, does it follow that $t|\dot{x}(t)|^2$ also converges to zero?

Comment: Hint: if $x(t)\to\ell$ then $t\ell^4$ CV implies $\ell=0$ so try some $x=\frac 1{t^a}$... (edit: I assumed $t\to\infty$).

Comment: Hi @zwim you are correct in assuming so. What does CV mean? Also I am sorry I have updated the question, I had made an error.

Comment: I often use these CV=convergent, CVS= simple convergent, CVU=uniform convergent, CVN=normal convergent, DV=divergent. Sorry if it was unclear.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks. Yes, so if I assume $\dot{x}(t) = -\frac{\alpha}{t^\alpha}$, does that lead me to say that $|\dot{x}|$ converges at the rate $\frac{1}{t^{\frac{\alpha}{4}}}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the function is some $\dot{x}$ doesn't really matter. The point is that $t x^2=\frac{tx^4}{x^2}$ is something going to zero divided by something going to zero, so what it does is indeterminate, depending on the rates the two pieces go to zero.

To get an example, look at $x=t^\alpha$. The original conditions are satisfied if $\alpha<-1/4$. Then $tx^2=t^{1+2\alpha}$ can still fail to converge if $\alpha>-1/2$.

Comment: Please go through the edit.

Comment: @SubhransuSekharBhattacharya Done (though the information you wanted was already there).

Comment: Yes, the problems with shaky self-studying math enthusiasts. Thanks a lot.